# How to use json.tool from the shell to validate and pretty-print language files without removing the unicode?

Tags: python, json, bash

**Ubuntu 16.04

Bash 4.4

python 3.5**

I received a bunch of language files from the translators at Upwork and noticed none of the files had the same line count. So I decided to validate and pretty-print them since they were in .json format and then see which lines were missing from each file, so I made a simple script to validate and pretty-print:

```
#!/bin/sh

for file in *.json; do
   python -m json.tool "${file}" > "${file}".tmp;
   rm -f "${file}";
   mv "${file}".tmp "${file}"
done
```

Now my Russian Langauge file looks like:

```
"manualdirections": "\u041c\u0430\u0440\u0448\u0440\u0443\u0442",
"moreinformation": "\u0414\u0435\u0442\u0430\u043b\u0438",
"no": "\u041d\u0435\u0442",
```

I would very much like to keep the content of the files untouched.

Comment: `json.tool` does not have an option for this, are you open to using other tools?

Comment: @AnthonySottile I'm always open to suggestions. I'd like to see how you would do it.

Comment: I think `jq . ` will preserve the unicode characters, not at a computer to verify though :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following equivalent Python script instead, which uses a subclass of `json.JSONEncoder` to override the `ensure_ascii` option:

```
import json
import os
import glob

class allow_nonascii(json.JSONEncoder):
    def __init__(self, *args, ensure_ascii=False, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, ensure_ascii=False, **kwargs)

for file in glob.iglob('*.json'):
    with open(file, 'r') as fin, open(file + '.tmp', 'w') as fout:
        fout.write(json.dumps(json.load(fin), cls=allow_nonascii, indent=4))
        os.remove(file)
        os.rename(file + '.tmp', file)
```

Comment: I am going to try this now.

Comment: This worked well and did 12 files @ 1mb each instantly. They are all  formatted the same way which makes things easy. Well done mate.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in `json.tool`:

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.5/Lib/json/tool.py#L45

The call to `json.dumps` does not allow to pass the keyword argument `ensure_ascii=False` which would solve your issue here.

You will have to write your own `json.tool`, monkeypatch it, or use third-party code.

***edit:*** I've proposed [PR 9765](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/9765) to add this feature to `json.tool` in Python 3.8.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

for filename in os.listdir('/path/to/json_files'):
    if filename.endswith('.json'):
        with open(filename, encoding='utf-8') as f:
            data = f.read()
            print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

Notice the `encoding` used with `open()`.  This SHOULD import the files and display them as necessary.  I think.

Comment: Appreciated the try.

Comment: So long as you got your answer.  :)